# How to redraw ctx.rect?

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

I would like to create a box around of rectangle element similar to Bounding Box. This box will be used as an alignment element in the future development (not really important now...)
The goal is anytime element rotates, Alignment Box (AB) must redraw itself... Basically. it needs to stay still, I mean without applying rotation (like I've mentioned before, exactly the same behaviour as a Bounding Box).

My problems are:

1. Anytime I click on element AB disappears.
2. When I rotate an element, AB rotates together with an element.

https://jsfiddle.net/redlive/7npzqcf2/

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Object.prototype, {
 redrawAlignmentLines: function(){
   this.canvas.renderAll();
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
  const rad = fabric.util.degreesToRadians(this.angle);
    const bb = this.getBoundingRect();

  ctx.rect(bb.left, bb.top, bb.width, bb.height);
    ctx.stroke();
    console.log('angleangleangle', this.angle, rad);
  }
});

var red = new fabric.Rect({
 id: 1,
  left: 200,
  top: 200,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  angle: 30,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
});
canvas.add(red);
canvas.renderAll();

red.redrawAlignmentLines();

canvas.on("object:rotating", function(e){
 e.target.redrawAlignmentLines();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-rc.3/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Comment: Do you want something like [this](http://fabricjs.com/bounding-rectangle) ?

Comment: Well... yes and no... What I need is to replicate same logic as a Bounding Box in the link you've sent me, but what I need is to add more stuff to it... I'll need to add Lines which will serve as alignment lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to achieve a goal I need. 
Basically, I've used an example from fabricJS [demo](http://fabricjs.com/bounding-rectangle) and changed a logic a bit.

https://jsfiddle.net/redlive/7npzqcf2/8/

```
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

fabric.util.object.extend(fabric.Object.prototype, {
    redrawAlignmentLines: function(){
    const ctx = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    const bb = this.getBoundingRect();

    this.setCoords();
    canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = 'magenta';
    ctx.save();

    if (this.alignmentLines.left) {
        ctx.moveTo(bb.left, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(bb.left, 600);
        ctx.stroke();  
    }
    ctx.restore();
  }
});

var red = new fabric.Rect({
  id: 1,
  left: 200,
  top: 200,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  angle: 30,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  alignmentLines: {
    top: true,
    left: true
  }
});
canvas.add(red);
canvas.renderAll();

canvas.on('after:render', function() {
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
        obj.redrawAlignmentLines();
    })
});
```